# SQL Query that returns various rows from one table when using a Condition WHERE on another table

Tags: sql, join, rows

I have these two tables:

**Factura**

```
    FacturaID (PK) int
    Fecha date
    Total money
```

**FacturaDetalle**

```
    FacturaDetalleID (PK) int
    FacturaID int FK on Factura.FacturaID
    ProductoID char(10) FK on Producto.ProductoID
    Precio money
```

**Producto**

```
    ProductoID (PK) char(10)
    Descripcion char(50)
```

Now to add some data:

```
INSERT INTO Producto (ProductoID, Descripcion) VALUES ('1', 'soda')
INSERT INTO Producto (ProductoID, Descripcion) VALUES ('2', 'papas')
INSERT INTO Producto (ProductoID, Descripcion) VALUES ('3', 'pan')

INSERT INTO Factura (Fecha, Total) VALUES ('Some Date', 100) SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() //Returns FacturaID = 1

INSERT INTO FacturaDetalle (FacturaID, ProductoID, Precio) VALUES (1, '1',  30)
INSERT INTO FacturaDetalle (FacturaID, ProductoID, Precio) VALUES (1, '1',  30)
INSERT INTO FacturaDetalle (FacturaID, ProductoID, Precio) VALUES (1, '1',  30)
INSERT INTO FacturaDetalle (FacturaID, ProductoID, Precio) VALUES (1, '2',  10)
```

What I want is a query that sends all 4 rows available on FacturaDetalle... but I only need `FacturaDetalle.Precio` and `Producto.Descripcion`.

However I haven't been able to do it..

I have tried things like this:

```
SELECT 
   Producto.Descripcion, FacturaDetalle.Precio 
FROM Producto 
INNER JOIN FacturaDetalle ON FacturaDetalle.ProductoID = Producto.ProductoID 
WHERE FacturaDetalleID.FacturaID = 1
```

I am getting this exception

> *The multi-part identifier "FaturaDetalle.ProductoID" could not be bound.
>
>   The multi-part identifier "Prodcuto.ProductoID" could not be bound.
>
>   The multi-part identifier "FacturaDetalleID.FacturaID" could not be bound.*

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you select Producto.* if only need price and description? This should work for you: SELECT Producto.descripcion , FacturaDetalle.Precio FROM Producto INNER JOIN FacturaDetalle ON FaturaDetalle.ProductoID = Prodcuto.ProductoID

Comment: Well you clearly have typo errors in all three exceptions:..look carefully : FaturaDetalle , FacturaDetalleID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change  FacturaDetalleId to FacturaDetalle in where condition

```
SELECT 
Producto.Descripcion, FacturaDetalle.Precio 
FROM Producto 
INNER JOIN FacturaDetalle ON FacturaDetalle.ProductoID = Producto.ProductoID 
WHERE FacturaDetalle.FacturaID = 1
```

Answer (score 5):

to avoid typos, you can supply `ALIAS` around tableNames.

```
SELECT  a.Descripcion, 
        b.Precio 
FROM    Producto a
        INNER JOIN FacturaDetalle b
            ON b.ProductoID = a.ProductoID 
WHERE   b.FacturaID  = 1
```

by the way in your original query, you have used `FacturaDetalleID` instead of `FacturaDetalle`